# B2B lightning checkout flow(standard)

Tags: community, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce, b2b, b2b-lex

does anyone had worked on B2B lightning checkout flow(standard) in salesforce.

I got this error when click on checkout button
I have selected Shipping address from Contact point Address also

Something went wrong. Cancel the current checkout process and try again.
Error: [An integration error occurred in PRICE_CART. Contact your admin.]

Comment: Is that the whole error message that you are receiving ?

Comment: Yes @SubratSrivastava I received that message only

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the price check integration that would need to be set up & represented in commerce administration settings within the internal commerce app (not experience builder workspace). The purpose would be to have a callout to an ERP to validate pricing if i recall correctly.